# Lost some wagtail group permissions after remove_stale_contenttypes - how to get them back?

Tags: django, wagtail

After refactoring some models in my Django/Wagtail project I had some stale contenttypes, triggering errors in the wagtail search app.

These errors could be fixed by running a `contenttypes` management command:

`./manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes`

Ok, I got warned about what will be deleted and there were indeed some group permission objects listed. Anyway, `remove_stale_contenttypes` did it's job and the wagtail search was back.

But now some permissions are missing: e.g. the "*Can access wagtail admin*" Group permission is completely missing, even for new Group instances.

How do I get the default permissions back (some were migrated once via [wagtail/admin/migration](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/migrations/0001_create_admin_access_permissions.py))? Ideally, I would like to restore all "default" permissions on my production site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code (to be run on the `./manage.py shell` command line) should to it:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
wagtailadmin_content_type, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(app_label='wagtailadmin', model='admin')
admin_permission, created = Permission.objects.get_or_create(content_type=wagtailadmin_content_type, codename='access_admin', name='Can access Wagtail admin')
```

This is [a bug specifically affecting the "Can access wagtail admin" permission type](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4444), and no other permissions should be affected.